# How to eliminate horizontal gap from side-by-side columns inside a Bootstrap card?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a card that goes like this...

[image]

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 p-2 ">
    <!-- Card -->
    <a href="https://www.example.com" class="card w-100 bg-white text-dark border-1 shadow-sm rounded-top rounded-bottom">

        <div class="card-header bg-white pb-0 pt-0 border-top">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 bg-success p-0">
                    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/braincloud/image/fetch/w_300,h_300,c_thumb,g_faces/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/groupm-dominic-grainger-thumbnail-1024x576.jpg" class="w-100">
                </div>
                <div class="col-6 p-0">
                                                <img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/groupm.com" class="img-fluid w-100 logocenter">                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Title -->
        <div class="card-body pb-0 pt-2 mt-0">
            <p class="card-title pt-2 font-weight-normal">How Europe Can Hit Addressable Scale: Grainger, GroupM</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Date -->
        <div class="card-footer bg-white text-muted small pt-0 border-top-0">Dec 13, 2018</div>
    </a>
    <!-- end .card -->
</div>
```

That is two images inside `.card-header`. Previously, it was one, but now I need the two images side-by-side. So I added the `.row`, with two 6-wide columns in it.

The problem - there are horizontal gaps either side of the image. How can I get rid of this? I want the images to reach the edge of the card (but also be accommodated by `.rounded-top` at the top).

I have tried a few things...

**On the `.card-header`...**

`.mx-0` does nothing

`.px-0` makes the images bleed *over* the card...

[image]

**On the `.row`...**

`px-0` does nothing

`mx-0` shrinks row/images down too small, which is the opposite of what I need...

[image]

Viewed through Chrome's Inspector, here is `.card-header`...

[image]

And here is `.row`...

[image]

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you can do one of two things, with your markup you would have to remove the horizontal margins and paddings on the `row` that contains the images, as well as removing the padding on the `card-header`, all of this can be done with `px-0` and `mx-0`, but you have to also round the corners on the images so the fit well with the rest of the card.

**EDIT:** I noticed the the remaining space on the corners of the header were due to a 2px border on the top side of the header, by removing that with `border-top-0` you can get rid of the space and you would just have to round the images with the same value that the header has, which is `calc(.25rem - 1px)`

The other alternative if you can change your markup a bit is using Bootstrap 4 `card` component like this:

```css
.card-header .row .col-6:first-child img {
  border-radius: calc(.25rem - 1px) 0 0 0;
}

.card-header .row .col-6:last-child img {
  border-radius: 0 calc(.25rem - 1px) 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Bootstrap 4 Card -->
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Your code -->
<div class="d-flex align-items-stretch col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 p-2">
  <!-- Card -->
  <a href="https://www.example.com" class="card w-100 bg-white text-dark border-1 shadow-sm rounded-top rounded-bottom">

    <div class="card-header border-top-0 bg-white pb-0 pt-0 border-top px-0">
      <div class="row mx-0 px-0">
        <div class="col-6 bg-success p-0">
          <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/braincloud/image/fetch/w_300,h_300,c_thumb,g_faces/http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/groupm-dominic-grainger-thumbnail-1024x576.jpg" class="w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-0">
          <img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/groupm.com" class="img-fluid w-100 logocenter"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="card-body pb-0 pt-2 mt-0">
      <p class="card-title pt-2 font-weight-normal">How Europe Can Hit Addressable Scale: Grainger, GroupM</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Date -->
    <div class="card-footer bg-white text-muted small pt-0 border-top-0">Dec 13, 2018</div>
  </a>
  <!-- end .card -->
</div>
```

Comment: > #1. "with your markup you would have to remove the horizontal margins and paddings on the row that contains the images, as well as removing the padding on the card-header, all of this can be done with px-0 and mx-0" --> This is what already leads to the too-narrow image formulation seen in my third image above. I'll comment separately on #2...

Comment: > #2. "The other alternative if you can change your markup a bit is using Bootstrap 4 card component like this" --> This is it - to be clear, your answer is essentially: a) don't put the two-image row inside a .card-header, just leave it inside .card, and b) use .no-gutters on .row. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertAndrews actually as it shows on the snippet, making the changes suggested on #1, it removes the small spaces at the sides of the images, so the images fill the entire width, the issue then happens with the borders, which don't look rounded. On #2 yeah, that's pretty much it, and you keep almost the exact same markup as the bootstrap card component

Comment: As you point out - "you have to also round the corners on the images so the fit well with the rest of the card". Even with answer working #2, there are a couple of Bootstrap quirks - i) I can't just added .rounded-top to each image, because what the left and right images, respectively, need are .rounded-top-left and .rounded-top-right - neither of which exist. ii) Even with .rounded-top applied, the image rounding doesn't match the line of the card rounding - white space is showing through https://i.imgur.com/HzUJad5.png

Comment: @RobertAndrews I think I was able to solve that, look at it in here, if it works for you I'll update the answer to reflect the changes https://imgur.com/a/asLpqMk

Comment: Updated the answer :)

Comment: Lovely - you've fixed Bootstrap :-) Weird mismatch. Wish it wasn't necessary. FYI, i) since scenario #2 involved *removing* .card-header, I've applied the CSS to .card instead, and ii) the first CSS rule needs img applied. Thanks.

Comment: "I noticed the the remaining space on the corners of the header were due to a 2px border on the top side of the header, by removing that with border-top-0 you can get rid of the space" --> Okay, so I could drop my border (border-0) or keep border-1 and add border-top-0... does that negate/affect my use of your extra calc at (.25rem - 1px)?

Comment: Hmm... don't think so, also there is no `border-1` class, keep that in mind... but the `border-radius` property should still take effect